# use a JSON object with a webjobs SDK and Azure queue

Tags: c#, azure, json.net

Just building a sample app to try and figure something out.

I have a class called messageClass:

```
namespace WebJobsSDKSample
{
    public class messageClass
    {
        string name { get; set; }
        string path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and a function:

```
namespace WebJobsSDKSample
{
    public class Functions
    {

        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message)
        {

            messageClass mess = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<messageClass>(message);

        }
    }
}
```

The program sets stuff up like so:

```
namespace WebJobSDK
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

                config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
            if (config.IsDevelopment)
            {
            }

            config.DashboardConnectionString = "";

            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();

            config.LoggerFactory = loggerFactory
                .AddConsole();

            var host = new JobHost(config);

            host.RunAndBlock();

        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run it it works, and if I put a messsage into the queue it gets picked up.
But it is not being treated as a JSON object.
If I put this in as a message:

{"path": "path here","name": "name here"}

then both of the fields for path and name are null.
This is what the string message shows in the debugger in the function:
"{\"path\": \"path here\",\"name\": \"name here\"}"

I have tried setting message as type of messageClass or Object instead of string as well.

Using Newtonsoft.Json;

Thank you,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any access modifiers on `path` and `name` properties, so they are by default private (whereas with a class omitting access modifiers would make it internal).  So while you can see the values while debugging, `JsonConvert` cannot and therefore can't set values on those properties.

Add public access modifiers to the properties and you should be good.

```
public class messageClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: man...I'm embarrassed I missed that!  I can't accept answer yet but will soon.